# Django - button redirecting to {% url 'index' %}

Tags: django, redirect, button

I can't find any solution on any article so I'm asking here.
I'd like to make button which is gonna redirect user to specific url.
I have already did it this way:

`<button onclick="location.href='create_recipe/'" type="button" >Create new Recipe</button>`

but instead of passing whole link I'd like to use `{% url 'some_view' %}` but I do not have an idea how I should do that.
Is it even possible to do that ?

It has to be `<button>`,

edit:

something like:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Create new Recipe</a></button>`

also does not work

Comment: Do you have `index` set in your urls.py?

Comment: ye, ```path('', index, name="index"), ```,
There is no problem in typical redirecting, something like: <a href={% url 'index' %}>some text</a> works correctly, but I want to user <button>

Comment: I would make a link look like a button. You can do that with CSS.

Comment: If you need to use a button because of a11y or something, then the onclick attr with a bit of JS like `onclick="location.href = \"{% url 'index' %}\""` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding this to the button:

`onclick="goToSomeView()"`

And then add this in script tag of html file:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   function goToSomeView(){
    document.location.href = "{% url 'some_view' %}"
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to user your method by I;m getting error 'recipes' is not a registered namespace and when I'm setting namespace it causes errors in other parts of app which I would prefer to avoid

Comment: Alrighty, no /need/ to set the namespaces. Principle is still the same, will it work? @KermitHQ

Comment: do you mean to do this like that: ```window.location.href= "{% url 'some_view' %}"``` ? No it doesn't

Comment: unfortunately also does not work

Comment: It should be `onclick` not `onClick`, you are not using react js. Now try.

Comment: I got rid of all content from my html file and put only ```<button onclick="redirectMe()" id='add-more' type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Create new Recipe</button>
 
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function redirectMe(){
    document.location.href= "{% url 'index' %}"}
  </script>``` and now it is working, I don't really know where the issue was. I'll just make a layout from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

As I see you're using bootstrap already, so the easiest way is to use the `a` element with the `type="button"` attribute.

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Create new recipe</a>
```

Below you can see that the result is the same, but for `button` you need to bind the `onclick` function. In this case I pointed to @nigel239 answer.

```js
   function goToSomeView(){
    document.location.href = "{% url 'index' %}"
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p class="lead">Using 'a' element</p>
<a href="{% url 'index' %}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Create new recipe</a>
<p class="lead mt-3">Using button</p>
<button onclick="goToSomeView()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Create new recipe</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`index` is your function which exist `views.py` file.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

path('',views.index, name='index'),
```

**HTML:**

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary"  href="{% url 'index' %}">Create new Recipe</a>
```

Comment: i got path('', index, name="index"), cuz I imported view this way from .views import (index,)

Comment: @KermitHQ, Please place it without button and see what it comes. `<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Create new Recipe</a>`

Comment: @KermitHQ Please check the updated answer for HTML part.

Comment: yea, that also work, I knew how to set href to <a> before but i was in need to user <button> instead od <a>

Comment: @KermitHQ `<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary"  href="{% url 'index' %}">Create new Recipe</a>`